Reduce the size of a Git pack file in Github
I am a collaborator on a project containing primarily R code. The project itself is only a few MB, but when I clone the repo locally, the local repo is 3 GB, almost all of which is the pack file (.git/objects/pack).
Using git verify-pack and git rev-list I have identified that the repository was tracking some vendor tar.gz files, and when I remove those locally with git filter-repo I can successfully get the repo down to a manageable size.
This solution, of course, only works for an existing local repo. Is there a way to modify the repo in Github (without torching it and starting a new one) so that it no longer generates the 3 GB + pack file on clone?

Clone locally, remove the file from all commits and force-push back.

@phd Even that probably won't do it. Unreferenced commits don't go away promptly on GitHub.

@matt The question is what to do "so it no longer generates the 3 GB + pack file on clone?" — emph.mine.

@matt Technically, even if GitHub keep old commits because they are shared between forks, during the clone, they won't be downloaded anymore and the pack file will be a lot smaller locally.

@phd If I do that and then submit a pull request, will it correct the problem on the main branch?

It should correct it, yes - though you will need to tell anyone else working with that repo that you're force pushing. As for unreferenced commits, GitHub (and others) will periodically garbage-collect repos, so while the unreferenced commits will still be on for a time, they'll go away before long.

@triphook No, a pull request will no work. A PR (merge) can only add to the repository, not remove. The owner of the repo should cleanup and force-push.

@phd If the owner does the cleanup on, say, the 'main' branch and does a force-push, will that have any effect on the other branches in the repo?

@triphook No, all branches should be cleaned up. git filter-repo does this for the entire repository.

I can see the following options (not in any particular order):

Live with it.
Raise a bug on the repo [and offer help fixing in].
Setup a new repo obsolete/freeze the old one (requires coordination).
Coordinate with others and remove the big files (git filter-repo and force push).
Start a new project that solves the same problem.

